# Sorl-thumbnail generates black square instead of image

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

I'm developing my project inside a Vagrant VM, the software version I'm using is:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Django 1.6
- Sorl Thumbnail 11.12
- Pillow 2.5.3

I have some pictures in the path `/var/www/django/my_project/media/icons` and I have a model with an **ImageField** pointing to that path.

I have also `THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True` in my *settings.py*

In my template I use thumbnail like:

```
{% thumbnail category.image "20" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}"></img>
{% empty %}
    {% thumbnail "png/no_image.png" "20" as im %}  # Thumbnail add the rest of the path to media
        <img id="no_image" alt="" src="{{ im.url }}" />
    {% endthumbnail%}
{% endthumbnail %}
```

There are some objects with image and some others without it and **both** shows just a black square instead of the image.

- Does anyone knows why is this happening ? I use Sorl-Thumbnail in many projects and never had this issue

I've tried to reset the full database, I used `python manage.py thumbnail clear` and `python manage.py thumbnail cleanup`

I've installed: **libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev zlib1g-dev**

*no_image.png is an image (red cross) **not** an **empty** image*

- Am I missing any library or dependency ?

I'm lost because as I said I've worked with Sorl-thumbnail in other projects, and never saw anything like this.

Any help would be much appreciated

---

## Edit

Here are some images I'm trying to display:

[image]
[image]

***( I have png and jpg libraries working on Pillow )***

And this is what I see in all cases:

[image]

## Edit2

The problem is with the background. When I upload a `png` image with transparent background sorl converts the image to `jpg` and set the background to black...

- Is there any way to keep the transparent background or avoid conversion ?
- Is possible to set the background to white ?

I tried with:

```
THUMBNAIL_COLORSPACE = None
THUMBNAIL_PRESERVE_FORMAT = True
```

but didn't work

Comment: When you say 'black square', is that the `no_image.png`? When you look at the actual path being generate in the `src` for the image, is it pointing to the sorl thumbnail cache path (something like `/media/cache/ab/fa/abf...e08.jpg`) i.e. is sorl actually creating the thumbnails?

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony The image no_image.png is a green circle and sor-thumbnail is generating the images in `/media/cache/ab/...` but this images are just black squares, it doesn't matter the contain on the image, sorl-thumbnail generates a black picture

Comment: Have you checked that `Pillow` installed with `png` support, `ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available` because when I used ubuntu there was problems with path to `zlib1g-dev` and others, so I resolved it `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib` and same for other libs, then `pip install -U Pillow`

Comment: @madzohan I think the issue you're saying is for x64 machines and my machine is 32, anyways I checked Pillow installation and it says `ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available`

Comment: Do you have an example of a image that you tried to make a thumbnail of and the result? Have you set any other sorl-thumbnail related settings?

Comment: @relekang the issue happens with all images, I show you here 2 of them. And I allways see the black square

Comment: Works for me with your requirements. 

See a sample app:

https://bitbucket.org/barseghyanartur/sorl-thumbnail-generates-black-square-instead-of-image

Comment: In settings.py is `DEBUG = False`?  Or, do you have any normal images (not run through Thumbnail) that are showing correctly?

Comment: @jcfollower it seems the issue is with the background, sorl is changing the transparent background to black background because the png images are converted to jpg... I don't know if maybe PIL could be better than Pillow for this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally solved !

To solve the issue with the black background:

- I updated **sorl-thumbnail** to `12.2`
- Added this 2 lines to settings.py:

  - `THUMBNAIL_COLORSPACE = None`
  - `THUMBNAIL_PRESERVE_FORMAT = True`
- Restart thumbnail database with `python manage.py thumbnail clear_delete_all`

Comment: I was still facing issues after this (`OSError: cannot write mode P as JPEG`), I ended up using these settings (since I don't care much about the image compression) `THUMBNAIL_PRESERVE_FORMAT = True THUMBNAIL_FORMAT = 'PNG'`. Did not change the `THUMBNAIL_COLORSPACE` setting (defaults to `'RGB'`).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug in that version of sorl-thumbnail related to bad meta-data. It is currently fixed in the release candidate currently on pypi. Since pip does not install RC by default you have to specify the version to install it. Try:

```
pip install sorl-thumbnail==12.1c
```

I tried it out with the python logo and it worked fine for me with 12.1c

Comment: It is weird, because actually I have almost same env:
`Django 1.6.7,
Sorl Thumbnail 11.12,
Pillow 2.5.3` except `Ubuntu`, I am on `OS X` and everything work smoothly

Comment: It's likely that you have either PIL or Pillow installed in your system (not in the virtualenv). You could try to recreate your virtual environment with --no-site-packages option and then install Pillow.